# Limit of a function is the function of the limit (no continuity or convergence)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a sequence of real-numbers $\{a_n\}_n$ and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=a$ where $a$ can be finite or infinite. Consider a function $f(\cdot)$ of $a_n$. Under which conditions
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(a_n)=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n)
$$

?

Similar questions have been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766509/prove-that-the-limit-of-the-function-a-sequence-is-the-same-as-the-function-of-t) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588458/for-a-continuous-function-f-and-a-convergent-sequence-x-n-lim-n-rightarro) but I would like to know whether we can get a similar result without assuming continuity of $f$ and $a$ finite.

Comment: Do you take $a_n$ fixed or must $\lim f(a_n)=f(\lim a_n)$ be true for all $a_n$?

Comment: Since you ask for a case in which $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists but it is not finite, I guess you assume $f$ to have domain $[-\infty,+\infty]$ ?

Comment: Short answer is no.  This condition is equivalent to continuity of $f $ at $a $.

Comment: Hence, imposing continuity of $f(\cdot)$, the result holds also for $a=\infty$ or $a=-\infty$?